# Log on option in windows service

Tags: windows-services

In windows service there is Logon option and there we can select local system or a specific user , hwo does it differ by choosing different options w.r.to service running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different login credentials have different permissions wrt the resources access.

If you set the logon credential to a user, that user's access may not give the service ample permissions to use whatever resources are necessary for it to function.

So setting the right user/service account for the service is important.

*How do I know what account is right for the service?*

If it is a service installed by a program (or something that already was installed with Windows) then the account should be correct.

If however it is some service you created (via some programming language), then you'll have to figure out what resources are required for that service to run properly and find the correct user/service account.